# OnClick JavaScript Button, Invalid or unexpected token error

Tags: custom-button, onclick

Here is the field I am trying to update, the far left is the picklist I am wanting to update. the field on the left is another picklist. both lists have the same values.

As you can see below I have tried a number of approaches. Is this possibly a limitation with the Javascript button?

Any help would be appreciated.

Example 1

00N5000000AIfdn = {!TEXT($User.New_Business_Admin__c)};

- Error: Invalid or unexpected token error

Example 2

app.New_Business_Admin2__c = {!TEXT($User.New_Business_Admin__c)};

- Error: Unexpected Token ; (I am not missing one nor do I have duplicates)

Example 3

app.New_Business_Admin2__c = '{!$User.New_Business_Admin__c}';

- Error: Field New_Business_Admin__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions.

Example 4

00N5000000AIfdn = {!$User.New_Business_Admin__c};

- Error: Field New_Business_Admin__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the quotes, as well as not encoding unsafe characters:

```
app.New_Business_Admin2__c = "{!JSENCODE(TEXT($User.New_Business_Admin__c))}";
```

This answer presumes you're trying to use the AJAX Toolkit (e.g. `sforce.connection.update`) to update the record via JavaScript.

Comment: You nailed it, that worked. I could have sworn I tried that too. Thank you very much!!